# Creating A Search Function From Dictionaries In Python

Tags: python, function, search, dictionary

So I have am making a code that requires me to be able to search an entire dictionary based on an input, this needs to be a function.Ideally the user would be able to put a value in, and the program would print out all of the subdictionaries that contain this input. 
Here is my code, and it doesn't quite work

```
animal=dict()
animal['1']={'ID': '21012', 'plot':4, 'year':'1993', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 42, 'hindfoot': 36, 'tag':'1EA0F9'}
animal['2']={'ID':'22012', 'plot':4, 'year':'1995', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 31, 'hindfoot': 37, 'tag':'0D373C'}
animal['3']={'ID': '23012', 'plot':17, 'year':'1996', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 25, 'hindfoot': 37, 'tag':'64C6CC'}
animal['4']={'ID': '24012','plot':21, 'year':'1996', 'species': 'PP', 'weight': 26, 'hindfoot': 22, 'tag':'1F511A'}
animal['5']={'ID': '25012', 'plot':22, 'year':'1997', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 53, 'hindfoot': 35, 'tag':'2624'}
animal['6']={'ID': '26012', 'plot':17, 'year':'1997', 'species': 'OT', 'weight': 14, 'hindfoot': 18, 'tag':'2863'}
animal['7']={'ID': '27012', 'plot':18, 'year':'1997', 'species': 'OT', 'weight': 23, 'hindfoot': 21, 'tag':'2913'}
animal['8']={'ID': '28012', 'plot':13, 'year':'1998', 'species': 'OT', 'weight': 36, 'hindfoot': 19, 'tag':'2997'}
animal['9']={'ID': '29012', 'plot':6, 'year':'1999', 'species': 'PM', 'weight': 20, 'hindfoot': 20, 'tag':'406'}
animal['10']={'ID': '30000', 'plot':14, 'year':'2000', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 41, 'hindfoot': 34, 'tag':'156'}

result=dict()

def search_data():
    key = raw_input ('Please Input Search Criteria:')
    for k in animal.items ():
        if key in animal['v']: #if k is in sub dictionary
            print animal ['v'] #print sub dictionary
            return results;


search_data();
```

So if you input an ID number, the program should print what ever sub dictionaries have that ID Number.

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: Do you actually have multiple subdictionaries with the same ID number?  Otherwise just use ID as the key.  In any case, using integers as keys in a dict is clunky and pointless, if you're doing that use a `list` to hold all of your `dict`s.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.items` returns key, value pairs, and as you want to match `'ID'` of each subdict with the user input so you should check if `subdict['ID'] == key`.

```
def search_data():
    key = raw_input ('Please Input Search Criteria:')
    for k, subdict in animal.items():
        if key == subdict['ID']: 
            return k, subdict    #return key and the sub-dictionary


print search_data();
```

**Demo:**

```
Please Input Search Criteria:29012
('9', {'plot': 6, 'weight': 20, 'year': '1999', 'ID': '29012', 'tag': '406', 'hindfoot': 20, 'species': 'PM'})
```